# How can I resolve a permission error when installing gnuplot from homebrew?

Tags: homebrew, open-source

I am trying to install gnuplot on my mac. after trying    `brew install gnuplot`, I get the following errors:

> You must 'brew link lua jpeg' before gnuplot can be installed

And when I try    `brew link lua jpeg` I get the following error:

> Could not symlink file: /usr/local/Cellar/lua/5.1.4/include/lualib.h
>   /usr/local/include is not writable. You should change its permissions.

Any suggestion? BTW, my XCode and brew are updated.

Comment: Let's see if someone knows an answer offhand, but if you would edit this to add the version of Xcode and OS X it works much better - current versions are very localized but questions about a specific combination can be very useful even a year or two down the road.

Comment: Sounds like /usr/local wasn't set up with the user you're using to install Homebrew with. What user are you running `brew` as, and what's the output of `ls -ld /usr/local /usr/local/include`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/include
chmod +w /usr/local/include
brew link lua
```